# How much cost can be charged for an hour in web development.?

Tags: contracts, pay-rate, price, price-per-hour, foreign-markets

I am a freelance web developer in India, charging between 250 and 300 rupees/hour for domestic clients.

Now I have discussions ongoing regarding certain projects in the Middle East. How much can I charge them per hour? Would it be the same rate as I charge for domestic clients, or can I increase the rate? If I can, what would be a fair rate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the cost (to me) of one hour of work?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/442/how-do-i-calculate-the-cost-to-me-of-one-hour-of-work)  http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1036/how-to-determine-what-to-charge-for-building-custom-android-applications?rq=1 -- Take a look at the right side of this page, under the **Related** headline. There are several existing questions about pricing.

Comment: It all depends on your skill set. Remember, people usually outsource development because they want it to be cheaper. Please be more specific about your skills and someone may be able to help.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as opinion-based (Freelancer SE cannot realistically have a question for all freelancer skills for all areas of the world). However, I think the post can be improved: there is a sub-question in here about charging the same amount in different areas of the world, for which people may be able to offer some real-world experience.

Comment: May I ask what are your skill in web development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hourly rate would totally depend on your own skills. If your client is a technical guy, it will take him, say, one hour of Skype calling to understand how good you are.

I run a startup web development company.
My hourly rates as per my skills and expertise (for all clients, irrespective of the geographic location) are somewhat like:

- PHP - $12 - $18
- Ruby on Rails - $20 - $30
- Java - $20 - $30
- PSD to HTML & Javascript - $13 - $18.

You have to define a standard for yourself according to the services you have to offer.

Comment: I generally just set my price at a minimum (~$25/hour) and raise it if I'll be working for a long time on a single project, but yes; try to set a price for your work and stick to it.

Comment: @Santa I agree with you. That is a good strategy as well. But, I encounter many technical clients who are developers themselves so they tend to differentiate rates for different platforms.

Comment: For a beginner does i seems a good pricing.?

Comment: To be frank, it depends on you. If you have a client who is willing to give you $50 an hour, it is a bonus for you. But, the rates I wrote are a standard rate for an Indian developer.

Comment: As someone who is not in India I can say quite clearly that cheapest is "maybe" ( although Eastern Europe often can undercut prices ) but as for the general quality of work I can say that more often than not I get called in to fix outsourced projects and my fee will range from $120 to $160 per hour depending on how much of a mess I have to deal with ( my clean slate development rate is $ 80 to $110 per hour depending on technologies used and how much work I am offered )...

Comment: Downvoted, with apologies. Workers in different areas of the world must try not to bad-mouth their competition based on their nationality, and the suggestion that "Indian developers are always considered to be some of the best" is always going to be highly subjective.

Comment: @halfer - Many of my clients said that and hence I had to mention it here too. Some clients have the impression of getting cheap labour and quality. If they get it via an Indian or any other asian country, they feel like that. On the other hand, I have had clients who only believe in American and European developers because they are willing to pay more and trust more in developers from these parts. So, for them, these developers are the best in the world. I did not know that sharing a real life example would be downvoted

Comment: I think you must have know how contentious that statement was going to be when you wrote it. I reiterate my wish that you do not try to compete on nationality - there is no link between nationality and quality, and it is approaching flag-waving nationalism to say so.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go with my favorite accounting answer on this one, "it depends". The direct answer to your questions is that for international developers I've heard them charging anywhere between between $12 to $55 per hour.

The more roundabout answer is it depends on the client. Unless you are working through a third party you have the opportunity to conduct a client interview to get as much information as possible: specifically what do they value and what does their budget look like?

For instance if their budget is $1000 and they want to get a number of features out in one week well then the most you can get out of them will be $25/hr. But what if its $10,000? Then your upper limit is $250/hr. How can you convince them you are worth that much? By aligning what you deliver around what they value.

What I've done is experiment from client to client. I've tried to offer different hourly rates or weekly rates. This way I can find what works best for not only me but the different kind of clients I've had.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I had looked into what you are asking; I had talked to some developers and found that the average rate they are charging internationally is approx. 25-30 USD/hr.
You can use the same as it is ideally an international project.

On the other hand, it would be better if you approximated what the amount of work required is, how much time it will take and how much are you expecting from it as a complete project. Once you are done with the calculations, quote the price per hour accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to supplement the existing answers.

The services you offer have a business value. For example, if your work may double their sales revenue but it only takes you 20 hours to do the work, you may want to charge more than 6000 rupees. You can make a proposal that sells these results rather than focusing solely on hourly rate.

This is the difference between business value and your going rate. I just had a client who needed some changes done which had a really low business value; their website had a bug that was just a minor inconvenience for them. The work cost a lot of time for me to fix, though, so they didn't think it was reasonable to spend so much time and money fixing such a seemingly small issue. I had to explain the lengthy process through email, and since they were a long-standing client they decided to move forward anyway. If I hadn't done a lot of work for them already I am sure they would've rejected my proposal.

You really have to balance your rate with a client's expectations. This is why sales is difficult to freelancers, especially in a global market where clients expect a lower, competitive price. You will find clients that focus solely on price. However, some people will understand what you offer: a partner that's willing to solve their issues and communicate effectively.

To answer your question more directly: price will be an issue to some. Since they are outsourcing their work, they may be shopping around. Research the market prices, but make sure at the very minimum that you price fairly for yourself (so that you can eat and live). Be confident in your proposal. If they object to your price despite your best proposal, you may also want to offer alternatives, like less work at a lower price.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your hourly rate doesn't matter what you do generally should depend on following factors:

1. Your Experience
2. Client's Budget
3. Difficulty Level
4. Your Availability / Deadline of the Project.
5. What others are charging for the same work.

These points should be sufficient to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Where in the middle east? Cairo and Beirut are not the same, for example. Beirut is one of the most expensive cities in the world.

I used to live in Beirut. I would charge between $20 and $30 if I was there.

I you're in other countries, maybe less.

But if you're working from India, and your regular rates are around $7/hour, then why quadruple them. Just double them and you will be comfortable with them while still having very competitive rates. Now you can drive people like me out of the market.

Comment: Really? I'm in Beyrouth right now and found a Android/iOS Developer around the corner. He takes 17$/hr.